# Retrieve QSlider child from a QGridLayout

Tags: qt, children, qtwidgets, qgridlayout

I want to acces the value of the QSliders that are in my QGridLayout, but I don't find the right command.
An example of what I try:

```
 QSlider* slider=ui->gridLayout->takeAt(1)->widget();
```

The error message I get is:

> cannot convert 'QLayoutItem*' to 'QSlider*' in initialization

Is there a command to ask the QSlider right away and not the widget?
Is it possible to cast? I tried it, but this also didn't work.
How can I solve this?

Comment: try with: `QSlider* slider = qobject_cast<QSlider *>(ui->gridLayout->takeAt(1)->widget());`

Comment: Note that [`QLayout::takeAt`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#takeAt) *removes* the specified item from the layout.  You might want [`QLayout::itemAt`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#itemAt) instead.

Comment: thanks, it does the job!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`QGridLayout::findChild<T>`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild) method:

```
QSlider *slider = ui->gridLayout->findChild<QSlider *>("widget_name"); // Name is optional
```

Or alternatively

```
QList<QSlider*> sliders = ui->gridLayout->findChildren<QSlider *>();
```

As pointed by G.M, [`QLayout::takeAt`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#takeAt) is used to safely remove and return a Widget from a QLayout, so not what you are trying to do.